# Trying to return all nested json dictionary values that contain a substring python

Tags: python, json

I want to return a list of all of the text that comes after the nested 'en' key and before the comma that separates that key from the rest of the dictionary

````
dictionary = {'title': 'a',
 'labels': {'label0': {'en': 'Statement',
   'ca': 'dog1',
   'bd': 'ေမးခြန္း ၁၀'},
  'label1': {'en': 'Hello how are you',
   'ca': 'cat6979309',
   'bd': 'turkey89'},
  'option0': {'en': 'No',
   'bd': 'turkey232',
   'ca': 'dog2'},
  'option1': {'en': 'Absoluelty not',
   'bd': 'turkey3',
   'ca': 'dog3'},
  'option2': {'en': 'Neutral ', 'bd': 'snake3', 'ca':'bat1'},
  'option3': {'en': 'Somewhat Disagree',
   'bd': 'turkey4',
   'ca': 'dog4'},
  'option4': {'en': 'For Sure',
   'bd': 'turkey5',
   'ca': 'dog5'}},```
````

I have tried this which isn't working, the goal is to have the function return something like sentences = ['Statement', 'Hello how are you', 'No', 'Absolutely not','Neutral'...]

```
def json(dic):

    sentences = []
    for (key, value) in dic.items():
        if "en" in value:
            sentences.append(value)
                return sentences
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to recurse through the nested structure. Here is a generator function that does so:

```
def get_key(data, key):
    if key in data:
        yield data[key]
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from get_key(v, key)

>>> list(get_key(dictionary, "en"))
['Statement', 'Hello how are you', 'No', 'Absoluelty not', 'Neutral ',
 'Somewhat Disagree', 'For Sure']
```